# Elasticsearch in Go check if field exists in a document

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-5

I'm using olivere's v.5 elasticsearch library - https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic

Trying to check if a particular field exists in a document. According to ES docs, it's possible - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

But I can't find a Go query in the library to execute that. I found the NewExistsService but I don't see a method to search by field name. I need something like

```
elasticClient.Exists().Field("datefield")
```

which returns true or false. But 'Field' is not a method of 'NewExistsService'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not even how the Elastic API in the docs you linked work, though. Per that linked page, it "returns documents that have at least one non-null value in the original field". It does not return true or false based on whether a field exists in an index - which is sort of an odd question in Elastic anyway, given that Elastic is schemaless.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, I'm looking for whether a field exists in a document, not an index.

Comment: Then just get the document and check for the field. You can use `StoreFields` to omit all other fields if the documents are overly large. Nothing like your hypothetical `elasticClient.Exists().Field("datefield")` could work because it doesn't specify a document ID.

Comment: did you find out how to do this?

Comment: for those who are still looking: query.Must(elastic.NewExistsQuery("someobject.somefield"))